# android emulator becomes unusable after swiping without clicking, only cursor movements

Tags: ubuntu, android-emulator

On Ubuntu, after opening my docked laptop screen to use the camera, and changing the setting to connect the emulator camera to my webcam.

Now the emulator is unusable because interacting with it using the mouse becomes impossible due to it swiping on simple cursor movements (no clicking).

This means simply moving the cursor over the emulator now creates random and bizarre actions.

I've closed my laptop screen and reverted the webcam changes, but it has not fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the touchscreen on the laptop registering a touch and not letting go.

Restarting or disabling the touchscreen fixes the issue.